# How to assign values to form fields when there is no attribute " name "?

Tags: python, authentication, mechanicalsoup

i want to fill in a form from a website using following code :

```py
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("Web page url")
browser.follow_link("login")
browser.get_url()
browser.select_form('div[class="p30"]')
browser.get_current_form().print_summary()

>>> <input class="form-input" id="mail" type="text"/>
>>> <input class="form-input" id="pass" type="password"/>
```

as you can see .print_summary() return exact fields that i want to assign values to, but there is no attribute "name" for any of them so i can't change it.
I've read Mechanicalsoup tutorial and the form in it has that attribute "name":

```py
<input name="custname"/>
<input name="custtel" type="tel"/>
<input name="custemail" type="email"/>
```

and it can simply be changed using:

```py
browser["custname"] = "Me"
browser["custtel"] = "00 00 0001"
browser["custemail"] = "nobody@example.com"
```

i'm new to mechincalsoup so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using mechanicalsoup to set value of form element w/o a name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52585753/using-mechanicalsoup-to-set-value-of-form-element-w-o-a-name)

Answer (score 1):

The `mechanicalsoup` [Q&A](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails) section has specificly answered your question:

> If you believe you are using MechanicalSoup correctly, but form
>   submission still does not behave the way you expect, the likely
>   explanation is that the page uses JavaScript to dynamically generate
>   response content when you submit the form in a real browser. A common
>   symptom is when form elements are missing required attributes (e.g. if
>   form is missing the action attribute or an input is missing the name
>   attribute).
>
> In such cases, you typically have two options:
>
> 1. If you know what content the server expects to receive from form
>      submission, then you can use MechanicalSoup to manually add that
>      content using, i.e., new_control(). This is unlikely to be a reliable
>      solution unless you are testing a website that you own.
>
> 2.Use a tool
>   that supports JavaScript, like Selenium.

Comment: Probably the right answer, yes: a field without a `name=` attribute is useless without JavaScript, so there's almost certainly some JavaScript code in the HTML page, and MechanicalSoup won't help.

Comment: @masoud Thanks , is selenium a better tool to work with ? I'm newbie and i just want to make sure that I'm going to use the best tool out there!